# Growing a classification tree manually

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, cart

I want to create some CARTs in R. I used Clementine a while ago for this purpose and remember I could go into "manual mode" and grow the trees by hand. I could manually choose which variable to use for what split and so on. Can this be done in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `rpart` library you can set the cost parameter in order to achieve certain splits. For example, if you have three variables $(X, Y, Z)$ and you want the first split to correspond to $Y$ then you could set the costs (100, 1, 100) or tune them manually. This works because, from the function documentation, costs "are scalings to be applied when considering splits, so the improvement on splitting on a variable is divided by its cost in deciding which split to choose."

Comment: That's a nice solution. I tried it and it works. Just one thing, it really only works to force the first split to be generated on one (or some) of the variables and it could ruin the structure of the tree if it is grown deeply right?